# Install Grafana Helm Chart together with the Grafana App For Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

On our Kubernetes Cluster here (Version 1.14.2) I have installed the following:
 - The Grafana Helm Chart (from [here](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/grafana))
 - The Grafana App For Kubernetes (the Grafana Kubernetes Plugin) (from [here](https://github.com/grafana/kubernetes-app))

Using the Grafana Kubernetes Plugin I did "Add a new cluster".
I filled in certificate details as they were provided by the Kube Config file. I saved and the Kubernetes Plugin created also automatically a Grafana Data Source.

In the Grafana "Data Sources" section I did "Save & Test" for the automatically created Data Source. It shows "Data source is working".

In Grafana I went into the automatically created "Cluster Dashboard" and none of the Graphs is working. There is a read "!" at the corner of each graph and on hovering it reads "Datasource named was not found". **That is the problem I have.**

"kubectl logs grafana-7d56d6ff84-4sqlc" Shows no errors.

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

```
Login to Grafana
      ↓
Add data source
      ↓
Choose data source type ( cloudwatch, ElasticSearch, MySQL, Prometheus, Graphite etc) 
      ↓
In settings section : Add URL and access (Server/Browser)
      ↓ 
     Save
      ↓
  Go to Home
      ↓
 Create Dashboard by selecting any one ( Graph, Table, Text etc)
      ↓
 Add data source
      ↓
 Monitor you data.

Hope this helps.
```